# Fire danger when using IoT components

Tags: circuit-design, circuit-protection

I am automating my house using components like ESP8266, 220 to 5V converters, relays etc.

How big is the risk of a fire starting from a component malfunction and how can I mitigate this? What should contain my design in order to minimize this risk?

Is there a book or some documentation that I should read?

Comment: Add a fuse when you use 220 to 5V converters.

Comment: That^^ and use **good quality** 220 V to 5 V power adapters, ones that are UL-listed, KEMA, VDU etc. approved. The ones sold in your country from a reputable source should have these markings/ratings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on where you live there should be a set of regulations governing the proper installation of electrical equipment. In the US that is the National Electric Code. Find the corresponding document for your region and follow all of its rules.

When purchasing equipment, be sure to buy devices that have been safety certified as necessary in your region. In the US, as Bimpelrekkie said, that is typically an Underwriter's Laboratory certification.